# I am getting a 'this is not a function' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am getting an `$("<div/>").text(value).html is not a function` error in the code below:

```
function htmlEncode(value) { 
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); 
}

function startImageUpload(imageuploadform, imagefilename){

    $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).html(
        '<div>' + 
        htmlEncode(imagefilename) + 
        '<button type="button" class="imageCancel" cancel_image_file_name="' + 
        imagefilename + 
        '">CANCEL</button></div>'
    );

    return true;
}
```

How can this error be fixed?

The strange thing is I have a similar code below but different function (stopImageUpload) and the code works fine below:

```
 function htmlEncode(value) { 
        return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); 
    }

    function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename) {
        imagecounter++;
        $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append(
            '<div>' + 
            htmlEncode(imagefilename) +
            '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' +
            imagefilename + 
            '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'
        ); 

        return true;   
    }
```

Link to application to see what is happening is here: [application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php)

Comment: what value r u getting? html or text???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('<div/>').html(value); //without text function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function htmlEncode(value) { 
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); 
}
```

If `value` in the above snippet is `undefined`, then `text()` returns the DOM Element's text content, not the element itself, causing the chained call to fail.